# How Can I train a system to identify patterns in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have **3 patterns** and a **time series**.

So, I have to identify this patterns on my time series.

For exemple: I have this pattern (**1,2,3**)
and I have this time series: (9,2,3,1,2,3,6,5,4,3)

So, I have to identify this pattern on the time series:
(9,2,3,**1,2,3**,6,5,4,3)

I am trying to do this using Pandas, but I didn't find a function or a algorithm that can help me. Does anybody have a hint for it?

Comment: `.str.contains('1,2,3')`

Comment: If you want just to identify if a list contains your pattern you can use any search algorithm like Linear search or use contains.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find particular pattern in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967805/find-particular-pattern-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
str((9,2,3,1,2,3,6,5,4,3)).count('1, 2, 3')
```

It returns the amount of `1, 2, 3`s there are in your tuple.