# How can I find a pattern in a DataSeries with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have this dataseries

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Values': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]},
                  index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:00'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:02'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:03'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:05'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:06')])
```

I have to find this pattern in my dataseries

```
pattern = [1,2,3]
```

So, It must return to me (for example):

```
20130101 09:00:02   1
20130101 09:00:03   2
20130101 09:00:05   3
```

I am trying do that using Pandas.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by "find the pattern". For example `df.iloc[pattern]['Values']` would return the answer you are looking for, however I'm guessing that is not what you are wanting to do. Can you give a bit more information on how you would like to identify patterns?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find particular pattern in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967805/find-particular-pattern-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Does iloc work with float numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Values': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]},
                  index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:00'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:02'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:03'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:05'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:06')])
pattern = [1,2,3]
print df.iloc[[int(df.index.get_indexer_for((df[df.Values==i].index))) for i in pattern]]
```

Comment: It returned me "Invalid sintax"

Comment: Can you pls share the exact error message? (it runs fine with python 2.7)

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: In which line? Pls copy the complete error dump and paste it here. (BTW - If you are using python 3.x then `print` statement would be changed to `print(df.iloc...)`)