# How to handle missing values in sequences of a certain length from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

**The essence:**

If a column contains a sequence of more than, let's say, 5 missing values, I would like to remove the corresponding indexes from that dataframe. So in a dataframe like below...

```
                A       B
2017-01-01 -0.0053 -0.0062
2017-01-02     NaN  0.0016
2017-01-03     NaN  0.0043
2017-01-04     NaN -0.0077
2017-01-05     NaN -0.0070
2017-01-06     NaN  0.0058
2017-01-07  0.0024 -0.0074
2017-01-08  0.0018  0.0086
2017-01-09  0.0020  0.0012
2017-01-10 -0.0031 -0.0020
2017-01-11  0.0027     NaN
2017-01-12 -0.0050     NaN
2017-01-13 -0.0063     NaN
2017-01-14  0.0066  0.0095
2017-01-15  0.0039  0.0028
```

...I would like to remove the indexes `2017-01-02` to `2017-01-06` so that the desired output would look like this:

```
                 A       B
2017-01-01 -0.0053 -0.0062
2017-01-07  0.0024 -0.0074
2017-01-08  0.0018  0.0086
2017-01-09  0.0020  0.0012
2017-01-10 -0.0031 -0.0020
2017-01-11  0.0027     NaN
2017-01-12 -0.0050     NaN
2017-01-13 -0.0063     NaN
2017-01-14  0.0066  0.0095
2017-01-15  0.0039  0.0028
```

How can I do that efficiently?

---

**The details:**

Here's a snippet to reproduce the dataframe:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1234)

# Reproducible data sample
def df_sample(rows, names):
    ''' Function to create data sample with random returns

    Parameters
    ==========
    rows : number of rows in the dataframe
    names: list of names to represent assets

    Example
    =======

    >>> returns(rows = 2, names = ['A', 'B'])

                  A       B
    2017-01-01  0.0027  0.0075
    2017-01-02 -0.0050 -0.0024
    '''
    listVars= names
    rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2017', periods=rows, freq='D')
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-100,100,size=(rows, len(listVars))), columns=listVars) 
    df_temp = df_temp.set_index(rng)
    df_temp = df_temp / 10000

    return df_temp

df = df_sample(15,list('AB'))
```

**Complications that I'm aware of**

If the dataframe were to have overlapping indexes with missing values accross several columns like this:

```
                 A       B
2017-01-01 -0.0053 -0.0062
2017-01-02     NaN  0.0016
2017-01-03     NaN  0.0043
2017-01-04     NaN     NaN
2017-01-05     NaN     NaN
2017-01-06     NaN     NaN
2017-01-07  0.0024     NaN
2017-01-08  0.0018     NaN
2017-01-09  0.0020  0.0012
2017-01-10  NaN    -0.0020
```

...then I guess any solution using `apply` column by column would render a temporary dataframe like this...

```
                 A       B
2017-01-01 -0.0053 -0.0062
2017-01-07  0.0024     NaN
2017-01-08  0.0018     NaN
2017-01-09  0.0020  0.0012
2017-01-10  NaN    -0.0020
```

... and then possibly ignore the original missing indexes for `column B` from `2017-01-04` to `2017-01-08`. That is perhaps just something one would have to accept though. But ideally, the solution should recognize that those indexes originally represent 5 sequentually missing values, and remove those indexes as well, so that the resulting dataframe looks like this:

```
                 A       B
2017-01-01 -0.0053 -0.0062
2017-01-09  0.0020  0.0012
2017-01-10  NaN    -0.0020
```

(But what about the last NaN there? That one I would simply `fill forward`. But doing the same with *every* missing value would be taking things to far.)

So I guess this is potentially a much more complex problem than I suspected initally (and maybe also thats the reason why the function `pandas.DataFrame.dropna` has no specific argument for it).

---

**What I have tried:**

**1. pandas.DataFrame.dropna**

I thought the argument `thresh` would be a way to go using [pandas.DataFrame.dropna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), but according to the docs that argument sets a threshold for *existing* rather than *missing* values:

> thresh : int, default None
>
> int value : require that many non-NA values

**2. Defining and finding patterns of nan column by column**

The following is a possible solution based on the suggested answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967805/find-particular-pattern-in-a-pandas-dataframe). It does however require you to define that you are looking for 5 and only 5 missing valeues in a sequence. To complete the solution I would also have to find the union of indexes accross all the lists that represent the indexes of the missing sequences for all columns, and then subset the dataframe accodring to that.

Thank you for any other suggestions!

Here is the whole thing for an easy copy-paste:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


np.random.seed(1234)

# Reproducible data sample
def df_sample(rows, names):
    ''' Function to create data sample with random returns

    Parameters
    ==========
    rows : number of rows in the dataframe
    names: list of names to represent assets

    Example
    =======

    >>> returns(rows = 2, names = ['A', 'B'])

                  A       B
    2017-01-01  0.0027  0.0075
    2017-01-02 -0.0050 -0.0024
    '''
    listVars= names
    rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2017', periods=rows, freq='D')
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-100,100,size=(rows, len(listVars))), columns=listVars) 
    df_temp = df_temp.set_index(rng)
    df_temp = df_temp / 10000

    return df_temp

df = df_sample(15,list('AB'))

df['A'][1:6] = np.nan
df['B'][3:8] = np.nan
dfi = df

# convert to boolean values
df = dfi
df = df.isnull()

# specify pattern
pattern = [True,True, True, True, True]

# prepare for a for loop
idx = []

# loop through all columns and identify sequence of missing values
for col in df:
    df_temp = df[col].to_frame()

    matched = df_temp.rolling(len(pattern)).apply(lambda x: all(np.equal(x, pattern)))
    matched = matched.sum(axis = 1).astype(bool)
    idx_matched = np.where(matched)[0]
    subset = [range(match-len(pattern)+1, match+1) for match in idx_matched]

    result = pd.concat([df.iloc[subs,:] for subs in subset], axis = 0).index
    idx.append(result)
print(idx)
```

Output (indexes for nan sequences column by column):

```
    [DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-02', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-04', '2017-01-05','2017-01-06'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None),
    DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-04', '2017-01-05', '2017-01-06', '2017-01-07', '2017-01-08'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)]
```

Comment: Is your index going to always be date times that are exactly 1 day apart? There is a way you can use closure and filter on the datetime index to do sliding window operations.

Comment: No, not at all. In fact, weekends will always be missing as well as random other weekdays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve it for you. It does not drop rows until the end, so it will correctly resolve the multiple columns as you want in the second scenario. I've used the `df` from your complications section for the output of the code below.

Explanation:

- We create another df where `NaN` values get assigned to zero and every finite value is assigned to 1 (If your initial `df` has zero values, you will need to first map them to any other number in this dummy `df2`, then `.fillna(0).astype('bool')`)
- Grouping by the cumulative sum of each column allows us to find where there are more than 5 consecutive `NaN` values. The comparison with the original df then ensures we aren't capturing the first non-null value.
- The mask is created **at the end** for any row which should have been dropped, so you resolve it properly for multiple columns with overlapping `NaN` values.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

## If the initial df contains values of 0 do this instead of the first line below
#df2 = df.copy()
#df2[df2==0] = 0.01
#df2 = df2.fillna(0).astype('bool').cumsum()

# Min number of consecutive NaN values to begin dropping
n_cons = 5

df2 = df.fillna(0).astype('bool').cumsum()
for col in df2.columns:
    df2[col] = df2.groupby(col)[col].transform(lambda x: np.size(x) > n_cons)
    df2[col] = df2[col] & df[col].isnull()

mask = df2.any(axis=1)

df[~mask]
#                 A       B
#2017-01-01 -0.0053 -0.0062
#2017-01-09  0.0020  0.0012
#2017-01-10     NaN -0.0020
```

Comment: Works very well. Thank you!