# Find pattern with defined start and end, but with unknown length

Tags: python, pandas

**The essence:**

This is a follow-up question to [Find particular pattern in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967805/find-particular-pattern-in-a-pandas-dataframe), but now I'm not looking for a fixed pattern. So how can you define a particular start and end to a pattern / time period and subset a pandas dataframe according to that?

**The details:**

Let's say that you have this dataframe:

```
            ColA  ColB
Dates                 
2017-07-07   103    92
2017-07-08    92    96
2017-07-09   107   109
2017-07-10   100    91
2017-07-11    90   107
2017-07-12   105    99
2017-07-13    90   104
2017-07-14    90   105
2017-07-15   109   104
2017-07-16    94    90
```

And let's say that the pattern you are looking for starts with `[107, 100]` in `ColA` and ends with `[90, 109]` in the same column (ColB is just there to illustrate that it's a dataframe and not a series). How can you subset the dataframe while not knowing how many observations that lie between them?

**Desired output:**

```
            ColA  ColB
Dates                 
2017-07-09   107   109
2017-07-10   100    91
2017-07-11    90   107
2017-07-12   105    99
2017-07-13    90   104
2017-07-14    90   105
2017-07-15   109   104
```

I know how to do this in a rudimentary way using nested for loops, but I'm hoping some of you have got a more elegant solution. Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more the starts with and ends with? Are they ranges for ColA and ColB? Last observation is 109 which falls after 107.

Comment: The pattern is restricted to ColA. ColB is just added to illustrate that it's a dataframe and not a series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a couple of values, you can use [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html). You will need extra logic to either account for `idx2` occurring *before* `idx1`, and to generalize for arbitrary adjacent values.

```
idx1 = (df['ColA'].eq(107) & df['ColA'].shift(-1).eq(100)).idxmax()
idx2 = (df['ColA'].shift().eq(90) & df['ColA'].eq(109)).idxmax()

print(df.loc[idx1: idx2])

            ColA  ColB
Dates                 
2017-07-09   107   109
2017-07-10   100    91
2017-07-11    90   107
2017-07-12   105    99
2017-07-13    90   104
2017-07-14    90   105
2017-07-15   109   104
```