# Get coherent subsets from pandas series

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm rather new to pandas and recently run into a problem. I have a pandas DataFrame that I need to process. I need to extract parts of the DataFrame where specific conditions are met. However, i want these parts to be coherent blocks, not one big set.

**Example:**
Consider the following pandas DataFrame

```
   col1  col2
0      3     11
1      7     15
2      9     1
3     11     2
4     13     2
5     16     16
6     19     17
7     23     13
8     27     4
9     32     3
```

I want to extract the subframes where the values of `col2` >= 10, resulting maybe in a list of DataFrames in the form of (in this case):

```
   col1  col2
0      3     11
1      7     15


   col1  col2
5     16     16
6     19     17
7     23     13
```

Ultimately, I need to do further analysis on the values in `col1` within the resulting parts. However, the start and end of each of these blocks is important to me, so simply creating a subset using `pandas.DataFrame.loc` isn't going to work for me, i think.

**What I have tried:**
Right now I have a workaround that gets the subset using `pandas.DataFrame.loc` and then extracts the start and end index of each coherent block afterwards, by iterating through the subset and check, whether there is a jump in the indices. However, it feels rather clumsy and I feel that I'm missing a basic pandas function here, that would make my code more efficient and clean.

This is code representing my current workaround as adapted to the above example

```
# here the blocks will be collected for further computations
blocks = []

# get all the items where col2 >10 using 'loc[]'
subset = df.loc[df['col2']>10]

block_start = 0
block_end = None

#loop through all items in subset
for i in range(1, len(subset)):
    # if the difference between the current index and the last is greater than 1 ...
    if subset.index[i]-subset.index[i-1] > 1:
        # ... this is the current blocks end
        next_block_start = i
        # extract the according block and add it to the list of all blocks
        block = subset[block_start:next_block_start]
        blocks.append(block)
        #the next_block_start index is now the new block's starting index
        block_start = next_block_start
#close and add last block
blocks.append(subset[block_start:])
```

**Edit**: I was by mistake previously referring to 'pandas.DataFrame.where' instead of 'pandas.DataFrame.loc'. I seem to be a bit confused by my recent research.

Comment: If you share the code you have so far it might be easier to answer. It is a bit unclear exactely what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I tried to adapt my current code to the example mentioned above. Is it any clearer now?

Comment: @Gretel_f You say that the start and end is important to you without any further specification, but I *think* the suggested solutions in the post [Find particular pattern in a pandas dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967805/find-particular-pattern-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column) can be of help!

Comment: @Gretel_f Did you see my answer? The 'grp' column holds the data you need. Each entry `>0` is one of your `blocks`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split you problem into parts. At first you check the condition:

```
df['mask'] = (df['col2']>10)
```

We use this to see where a new subset starts:

```
df['new'] = df['mask'].gt(df['mask'].shift(fill_value=False))
```

Now you can combine these informations into a group number. The `cumsum` will generate a step function which we set to zero (via the `mask` column) if this is not a group we are interested in.

```
df['grp'] = (df.new + 0).cumsum() * df['mask']
```

**EDIT**

You don't have to do the group calculation in your `df`:

```
s = (df['col2']>10)
s = (s.gt(s.shift(fill_value=False)) + 0).cumsum() * s
```

After that you can split this into a `dict` of separate DataFrames

```
grp = {}
for i in np.unique(s)[1:]:
    grp[i] = df.loc[s == i, ['col1', 'col2']]
```

Comment: sorry, for answering late. I tested it and it seems to work quite fine up to the point of showing the blocks in 'grp'. However, a final step that neatly splits the groups into separate DataFrames would be nice, as this was the ultimate goal for me to have. Just so it answers the question completely.  

Also, just out of curiosity: I tried to combine all three lines into one big statement (without the "help columns") and I can't seem to make it work. Any ideas?

Comment: I added some code to generate new DataFrames. Combining all lines is possible but you have to repeat the 'mask' code multiple times and this just doesn't look good.

Comment: Your EDIT works perfectly. Thanks a lot! This is exactly what i was looking for. I'm already accepting your answer, however, it would be nice for future users to maybe explain what each statement does. I admit, I'm still a bit confused by the `cumsum() * s` statement.