# Python: I would like to return a subset of dataframe based on a list, if the records are ordered the same way the list is

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I have a dataframe that has more that a thousand records and I would like to return a sliced dataframe where the values are ordered similarly to the list.

e.g.

```
lst = [0,1,0,0,0,1]
```

## Input

```
    date season hot_or_cold
 0   2012-01-01 Winter 0
 1   2012-01-02 Winter 1
 2   2012-01-03 Winter 0
 3   2012-01-04 Winter 0
 4   2012-01-05 Winter 0
 5   2012-01-06 Winter 1
 6   2012-01-07 Winter 1
 7   2012-01-08 Winter 1
 8   2012-01-09 Winter 0
 9   2012-01-10 Winter 1
 10   2012-01-11 Winter 0
    # 1 - hot
    # 0 - cold
```

## Output

```
    date season hot_or_cold
 0   2012-01-01 Winter 0
 1   2012-01-02 Winter 1
 2   2012-01-03 Winter 0
 3   2012-01-04 Winter 0
 4   2012-01-05 Winter 0
 5   2012-01-06 Winter 1
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! You seem to be under the impression that StackOverflow is a site where you post a problem and get some code in return. This is in fact not the case. Your question will most likely be closed or even deleted shortly. To prevent this from happening in the future, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [take a look at the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular, [make yourself famlilar as to what is regarded as on-topic around here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Sorry if the way the tables turned out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basic question is finding some pattern in dataframe and i got this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967805/find-particular-pattern-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column) and have implemented same.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

arr = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = arr, columns=['binary'])
pattern = [0,1, 0, 0, 0, 1]

matched = df.rolling(len(pattern)).apply(lambda x:all(np.equal(x, pattern)))
matched = matched.sum(axis = 1).astype(bool)   #Sum to perform boolean OR

idx_matched = np.where(matched)[0]
subset = [range(match-len(pattern)+1, match+1) for match in idx_matched]

result = pd.concat([df.iloc[subs,:] for subs in subset], axis = 0)

result
```

Comment: @deepak_sen, thank you. The link you provided me with helped me return exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Define 2 following functions:

1. Find match between *s* (a *Series*, longer) and *lst* (a list, shorter).

   ```
   def fndMatch(s, lst):
       len1 = s.size
       len2 = len(lst)
       for i1 in range(len1 - len2 + 1):
           i2 = i1 + len2
           if s.iloc[i1:i2].eq(lst).all():
               return (i1, i2)
       return (None, None)
   ```

   When a match has been found, the result is both slice borders,
   otherwise a pair of *None* values.
2. Get a fragment of *df* with *hot_or_cold* column matching *lst*:

   ```
   def getFragment():
       i1, i2 = fndMatch(df.hot_or_cold, lst)
       if i1 is None:
           return None
       else:
           return df.iloc[i1:i2]
   ```

When you call it (`getFragment()`) the result is:

```
         date  season  hot_or_cold
0  2012-01-01  Winter            0
1  2012-01-02  Winter            1
2  2012-01-03  Winter            0
3  2012-01-04  Winter            0
4  2012-01-05  Winter            0
5  2012-01-06  Winter            1
```

Answer (score 0):

other way with accumulate function

```
from itertools import accumulate
import pandas as pd 
def accum(x):
    return list(accumulate(x))

lst = [0,1,0,0,0,1]
f = lambda x : accum([[i] for i in x])
b = df.groupby(['season'])['hot_or_cold'].apply(f)
df['col_accum2']  =  [(('Match ' if item[-len(lst):] == lst else 'NotMatch') if len(item) >= len(lst) else 'small list'  ) for subitem in b for item in subitem]
```