# Finding a swing pattern in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, finance

The title is not the best but I am not sure how to describe my problem in a line.

The problem I have is that I want to calculate whether some values, say A, B, C, D, occur in order.

| A | B | C | D | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1! | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1! | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1! | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1! | 1 |

In the table above, values of A, B, C, D are calculated individually. They are 1 if they pass a certain threshold and 0 otherwise.
My question is that I want to identify when A = 1 occurs before B = 1 occurs before C = 1 occurs before D = 1. In this case, from row 3 onwards (marked with an exclamation point), each value is consecutively 1. However, for A in row 1, i ignore A = 1 because B = 0 in the next row.

I tried implementing a for loop but that takes way too long. I am sure there is a more efficient method. My data is stored in a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Does this solve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967805/pandas-how-to-find-a-particular-pattern-in-a-dataframe-column?

Comment: it would also help if you provided the dataframe as data

Answer (score 1):

Try `shift` and `np.prod`:

```
# we shift `A` by 3 rows, `B` by 2, ...
# then take product of the shifted values
df['Total'] = np.prod([df[col].shift(3-i, fill_value=0) 
                       for i,col in enumerate(['A','B','C','D'])], 
                      axis=0)
```